Copy file from terminal into clipboard and paste in Finder
What I can do is:

open finder,
copy a file, or directoy
paste it in some other directory

What I want is:

open terminal
copy a file (the name?) into my clipboard
open finder
paste it in some directory

Observations (file and folder are used interchangeably):
If I copy some file from finder and paste it in my terminal, I get the full path:
/Users/<USER>/Downloads/<filename>.
If I paste it into a text field, e.g., firefox, I only get
<filename>.
If I paste it in finder I get a copy of the file in corresponding directory.
If I preview the content in Maccy, I see:
file:///Users/<USER>/Downloads/<filename>
What I tried is:
echo "file://$(pwd)/<filename>" | pbcopy
But this is not the same content in my clipboard as I cannot paste it in finder.
Thank you in advance for any tips:)

What you're currently copying to the clipboard is not the file, it's some text that -- if interpreted as a URL -- points to the file. Do any of the answers to "Is there a simple way to copy a file to clipboard in Mac terminal?" and/or "How to use terminal to copy a file to the clipboard?" do what you're trying to accomplish?

Why not go for full terminal based workflow by using filemanagers like vifm, ranger, nnn etc

@GordonDavisson Thank you, I need to check a little bit, but this looks very promising already

@AivarPaalberg I want to be able to copy a file using vifm and then paste it in another application :)

There are different types of data in the clipboard. (See NSPasteboard Type documentation) Observe it yourself in "clipboard viewer" in Xcode additional tools.
One type of data can be converted to many others, and they may have a different format. Hence your experience of pasting in different programs.
You will likely need to use the AppKit framework to write to the clipboard and simultaneously set the data type in your clipboard. See documentation for NSPasteboard.
